# Error when checking : expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [28,28,3]

Tags: tensorflow.js

I trained a model according to the tutorial "TensorFlow.js - Recognizing Handwritten Digits with CNN": "my-model.json", and then I loaded this model.

Next, I try to use the laptop camera to get the content, and then make predictions based on the content captured by the camera, but the previous models are all 1 color channel. Is there a way to identify the 3 captured by the camera without changing the model? The content of the color channel.

Or some tensorflow.js api can realize to convert the content of 3 color channels to the content of 1 color channel.

```
async function run() {
    const webcamElement = document.getElementById('webcam');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('./model/my-model.json');
    console.log(model)
    const webcam = await tf.data.webcam(webcamElement,{
        resizeWidth:28,
        resizeHeight:28
    });
    while (true) {
        const img = await webcam.capture();
        console.log(img)
        img.print();
        const result = await model.predict(img);

        document.getElementById('console').innerText = `
          prediction: ${result[0].className}\n
          probability: ${result[0].probability}
        `;
        // Dispose the tensor to release the memory.
        img.dispose();

        // Give some breathing room by waiting for the next animation frame to
        // fire.
        await tf.nextFrame();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

Comment: so you're asking how to convert RGB tensor to grayscale one? and how is the title related to that? title implies that you're likely missing a batch dimension in input.